# Differences between EC2 Auto Scaling Group (EC2 ASG) and Elastic Container Service (ECS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-auto-scaling

From what I've read so far:
EC2 ASG is a simple solution to scale your server with more copies of it with a load balancer in front of the EC2 instance pool
ECS is more like Kubernetes, which is used when you need to deploy multiple services in docker containers that works with each other internally to form a service, and auto scaling is a feature of ECS itself.

Are there any differences I'm missing here? Because ECS is almost always a superior choice to go with if they work as I understand.

Comment: ECS uses [Application Auto Scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/application/userguide/what-is-application-auto-scaling.html) service which is also used by many other services. EC2 instances use [EC2 Auto Scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/what-is-amazon-ec2-auto-scaling.html) which is  a separate service. There is also [AWS Auto Scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/plans/userguide/what-is-aws-auto-scaling.html) as a bonus to add to a confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right, in a very simple sense, EC2 Autoscaling Groups is a way to add/remove (register/unregister) EC2 instances to a Classic Load Balancer or Target Groups (ALB/NLB).

ECS has two type of scaling as does any Container orchestration platform:

1. [Cluster Autoscaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cluster-auto-scaling.html): Add remove EC2 instances in a Cluster when tasks are pending to run
2. [Service Autoscaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-auto-scaling.html): Add/remove tasks in a service based on demand, uses [Application AutoScaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/application/userguide/what-is-application-auto-scaling.html) service behind the scenes